# How to set Postgres global variable on session from spring data jpa context

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Basically I want to execute this query
***set public.ownerId = 'Owner-3';***

I have tried this in JPA, but no luck. Getting unexpected token set error .

```
 @Modifying
 @Query(value = "set public.ownerId = :ownerId;")
 public void setGlobalVariableOwnerId(String ownerId);
```

```
Error:
2021-03-31 10:19:07.243 ERROR 1 --- [      main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker    : line 1:1: unexpected token: set
2021-03-31 10:19:07.245 ERROR 1 --- [      main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker    : line 1:1: unexpected token: set
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: set
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:212) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
```

If I hardcode the value instead of parameter like this ***set public.ownerId = 'Owner-3'*** .It works.

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happends if you change to ```@Query(value = "set public.ownerId = ?1")```

Comment: engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
 org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1".        @Query(value = "set public.ownerId = ?1", nativeQuery = true)

Answer (score 2):

For preparedstatements, you have to use, you have to use **[set_config](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-admin.html)** method of Postgre.

Your query should be something like :

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT set_config('public.ownerId',:ownerId, false)")
```

- The query will return the value you set.
- The third paramater is about the scope: false for session and true for transaction.